# PHP daemon parent database connection lost

Tags: php, database, daemon

I've a problem designing a quite simple PHP daemon process.

We've a class that establishes a database connection, caches lots of data and can do some processing on that data.

The daemon process ist started, instantiates a the class and then binds to a socket to wait for requests. A new child process is spawned upon each request.

Problem: Database connection from parent is closed after first client disconnect (destructor is called, database link is lost).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the child process connect to the database or route database requests through the parent process using some IPC mechanism.